# Standards for Electrocardiography and Photoplethysmography

Tags: heart-rate, electrocardiogram

Electrocardiography and Photoplethysmography are two techniques/devices that are commonly used to measure heart rate.

My question is, ***clinically speaking***, what are the standards these devices must have in terms of how fast it must output heart rate and how accurate it must get?

Constraint your answer for ANSI,AAMI, and ISO standards. Thank you in advance.

Note:Pointing any source would be nice.

Comment: What has your research found so far?

Comment: I can't found nothing , that's why I asked